# Binding ColumnDefinitions in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding, grid

I have two separate Silverlight usercontrols containing grids and i want these to share a set of columndefinitions. The columndefinitions must be created dynamically. How can i do this?

Comment: Binding is probably a confusing term to use.  How much of the column definition is dynamic, can you have a set of prepared templates for each "type" of cell?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add them in code if that is sufficient:

```
private void CreateColumnDefinitions(Grid grid)
        {
            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(
                new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(10, GridUnitType.Star) });

            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(
                new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(5, GridUnitType.Star) });

            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(
                new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(5, GridUnitType.Star) });
        }
```