# How can I databind a list of integers to Grid ColumnDefinitions

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, data-binding

I have a set of integers:

```
public ObservableCollection<int> Scores = new ObservableCollection<int> {
    10, 30, 50
};
```

Which I would like to result in something that renders like the following XAML when bound:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0">10</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1">30</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2">50</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

How can I write a databinding to do this?

Comment: can't you use an itemsCollection element instead of specific textblocks?

Comment: @Clueless: Almost certainly. I have no real experience with databinding. I want the databound output to appear the same as the XAML I posted. I have no real clue how to get there.

Comment: Are you just trying to display some data in a grid or do you actually want set the width of the columns using the data in your collection? If you just want to display data why not just use a DataGrid and set the ItemSource?

Comment: @ReinardMavronicolas: The width is the key thing here. I'm not too interested in showing the data.

Comment: Not sure you can bind the column widths. However, you can dynamically set the widths of the columns at runtime. Loop through your collection and set the width. This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095124/binding-columndefinitions-in-silverlight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like the following:

```xml
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Scores}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"
                        Background="Yellow" Width="{Binding}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

I'm using a `Border` with a `TextBlock` inside it, but you can replace that with something else if you wish.  The important thing is the `Width` binding.

Note also that `Scores` must be a property.  In your code above you're creating a public field, but binding only works with properties, not with fields.

**EDIT**: if you want to use a `Grid`, you could try something like the following user control.  This user control has a dependency property for the widths of the grid, and recreates the grid every time the collection changes.

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public partial class BindableGrid : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty WidthsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Widths",
                                        typeof(ObservableCollection<int>),
                                        typeof(BindableGrid),
                                        new PropertyMetadata(Widths_Changed));

        public BindableGrid()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<int> Widths
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<int>)GetValue(WidthsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(WidthsProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void Widths_Changed(DependencyObject obj,
                                           DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var grid = obj as BindableGrid;
            if (grid != null)
            {
                grid.OnWidthsChanged(e.OldValue as ObservableCollection<int>);
            }
        }

        private void OnWidthsChanged(ObservableCollection<int> oldValue)
        {
            if (oldValue != null)
            {
                oldValue.CollectionChanged -= Widths_CollectionChanged;
            }

            if (Widths != null)
            {
                Widths.CollectionChanged += Widths_CollectionChanged;
            }

            RecreateGrid();
        }

        private void Widths_CollectionChanged(object sender,
                                              NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // We'll just clear and recreate the entire grid each time
            // the collection changes.
            // Alternatively, you could use e.Action to determine what the
            // actual change was and apply that (e.g. add or delete a
            // single column definition). 
            RecreateGrid();
        }

        private void RecreateGrid()
        {
            // Recreate the column definitions.
            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();
            foreach (int width in Widths)
            {
                // Use new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) for a "*" column.
                var coldef = new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(width) };
                grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(coldef);
            }

            // Now recreate the content of the grid.
            grid.Children.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < Widths.Count; ++i)
            {
                int width = Widths[i];
                var textblock = new TextBlock() { Text = width.ToString() };
                Grid.SetColumn(textblock, i);
                grid.Children.Add(textblock);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML for this `UserControl` contains only `<Grid x:Name="grid" />` inside the `<UserControl>` element.

You could then use it in XAML as follows, assuming you've bound `somePrefix` to the namespace `YourNamespace`:

```xml
    <somePrefix:BindableGrid Widths="{Binding Path=Scores}" />
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to do something more complicated, so I really need to use a grid. The aim is to use alternating grid cells to "justify" rectangles. In lame ASCII art: `AAAAAAAA_____BBBBB_____C_____DDDDDD`. I can achieve this, for instance, with column widths of `80px`, `*`, `50px`, `*`, `10px`, `*`, and `60px`. This would be generated from an int array of `{80, 50, 10, 60}`. However, I think seeing how to do the simple case would be enough for me to work out the complex case.

Comment: @Eric: It's a fair bit of work to use a `Grid` like this.  You'll have to use code-behind to create the column definitions in the grid.  Nonetheless, I've edited my answer to provide an example of how you might do something like this.